Unable to assert chinese text using selenium java in intellij
I am facing a problem during assertion of chinese text
trying to Change language on the application from English to chinese and assert the text displayed
I am using Cucumber + Testng +Selenium + java+ Intellij
But the asserting is failing.. Added the screenshot below

 @Then("Verify all the content is working as expected {string}")
public void verifyAllTheContentIsWorkingAsExpected(String language) {
    Assert.assertEquals(new Login().getTextLoginType("Email"),"电子邮件");

I have already checked UFT-8 and tried other solutions found in here.. it is giving the same error..
Please help on how to fix this

What happens in getTextLoginType("Email")? That's where the wrongly encoded text comes from so you should check that code. Also please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask right now none can help you because your question is missing the info needed for a good answer.

Thanks for checking.. it worked after adding -Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8   under .vmoptions

Well done! You should consider writing that as an answer. It might help other people!
